# Strip away characters in array

Tags: javascript

I am using a 3rd party script for uploading files and when I upload multiple files I get the names in this format:

```
[{"file":"0:/gIpVCEAe4eiW.jpg"},{"file":"0:/5yA9n2IfNh65.jpg"}]
```

I just want the actual file names. I wish I could post some code of what I have tried but I can't think of many options. I can't get .split alone to do what I want.

Comment: Can you give examples of the actual file names

Comment: You want to check the documentation of the 3rd-party script I guess. Based on the information in your question we won't be much help.

Comment: @Andy, the documentation doesn't show you how to do it the way I want to do it which is to submit via Ajax.

Comment: @AshayMandwarya, those are the actual file names. Anything you upload is renamed with random characters like that ie: `gIpVCEAe4eiW.jpg`

Comment: Is your question, how do I remove `0:/` from the the values?

Comment: @Andy, not really. The question is how do I get just `gIpVCEAe4eiW.jpg` and `5yA9n2IfNh65.jpg` as those are the 2 names I want to insert into the database.

Comment: This data is in JSON format.  Use JSON.parse(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array and return the [`replaced`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) filename. You'll get a new array back.

```js
const arr = [{"file":"0:/gIpVCEAe4eiW.jpg"},{"file":"0:/5yA9n2IfNh65.jpg"}];

const out = arr.map(obj =>  {
  return obj.file.replace('0:/', '');
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: That's beautiful.

Comment: @Andy, that is working nicely, thank you. I am trying to insert this into mongo db but it is inserting it like `gIpVCEAe4eiW.jpg, 5yA9n2IfNh65.jpg`. Would I need to do something like destructuring in order to get each file name individually and not in an array?

Comment: @Andy, my database format is basically `images: [
        {
            name: {
                type: String
            }
        }
    ]`

Comment: @Andy, and that means that each image will have it's own unique id. So, I would need to store each image name individually even though it is being stored in an array. I am new to mongo so still also trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: Probably you can just iterate over the array with an insert on each iteration. Or perhaps, because the insert will be an async operation, create an array of insert promises and use `Promise.all`. It's really outside the scope of this question tho. You should probably ask another one if you get stuck.

Comment: @Andy, fair enough. Will fiddle around and ask another question if necessary. Thanks for your answer, it was most helpful.

Comment: The `promises` code might [look something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/utqmf46j/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to perform a transformation on each element in the array.

First we flatten the array of objects to an array of strings, next we cut off the `0:/` with a split

```js
let files = [{"file":"0:/gIpVCEAe4eiW.jpg"},{"file":"0:/5yA9n2IfNh65.jpg"}]
let result = files
  .map(f => f.file)
  .map(f => f.split('0:/')[1])
  
window.alert(result.join(', '));
```